# how to define a default/fallback block in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
body
    header.l-header.l-site-width
        block header

    // include the block with the name body form whatever file that uses layout
    .l-body.l-site-width   
        block body

    footer.l-footer.l-site-width
        block footer
```

now i don't specify a header block in the file that is using the layout, i would like to use a default include.

I tried:

```
block header || "something else"
```

in the best case:

```
block header || include ../partials/base/header
```

it does not work, but does not trow an error.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually just write your default code in the header block.

```
block header
  include ../partials/base/header
```

If you now extend your layout you can overwrite the contents of the block with a simple standalone `block` statement.

```
extends layout

block header
  ... your code ...
```

Alternatively you can use `append` or `prepend` to add to the block, in this case the old content persists.

Comment: oh i did not get that it overwrites it by default! thank you.